# "Someone talking" or "someone is talking"?

Tags: sentence-construction

There is a phrase in textbook: "You will hear someone talking about body language." Isn't it supposed to be "You will hear someone is talking about body language."? Google search seems to imply, that both "someone talking" and "someone is talking" are both valid options. And I always thought, that "someone talking" is incorrect one. Could someone explain to me, why this isn't the case?

Comment: No, you will hear a noise. You will hear someone talking. taking is a noun. A noun.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly correct to refer to *hearing someone talking/shouting/singing* etc. if they are doing so in your hearing.

We would only use *I hear he is talking* if you had been informed by another person that someone was taking part in a conversation, or giving a talk (lecture), in another place.

Comment: I've been thinking. If "talking" is not a verb, but a noun in this example, shouldn't it supposed to be: "You will hear someone's talking about body language." As if "You will hear talking of someone about body language."

Comment: I didn't say that _talking_ was not a verb. See [this explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing)